# while scrolling UITableView, custom cells are jerking/Dancing/jumping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to Swift/iOS programming and stuck for weeks on this issue.
For the first time whenever tableview is scrolled, custom cells jerks and once u came all the way down and go back jerking stops.

Tried doing this stuffs:

•Making Cells and ImageView Opaque

•Caching cell height, since all the cells have different height.

•cell layer shouldRasterize = True

Scrolling slug shown in video: Link Here

Link Here: http://vimeo.com/239224021

Any Reasons this might be happening.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't see anything weird there in the video.

Comment: @iPeter uploaded new video link. Can you check now.